# Collapse and expand all

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement expand/collapse all functionality.
I have a list of expandable items, with a button in the top right which allows the users to expand and collapse everything.

Currently, my code works if everything is expanded/collapsed together, but does not work properly when the user expands a few (and not all) of the elements. It simply switches the collapsed/expanded elements. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q63Dx/8/)

Here is my jQuery code that is being run:

```
$('div.srcprojects').hide();
$('.projectscontainer').on("click", "span.destproject", function (){
    $(this).siblings('.srcprojects').toggle().end().siblings('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
}).on("click", "div.destarrow", function (){
    $(this).parent().find("span.destproject").trigger("click");
});

$('body').on("click", "span#expandcollapse", function (){
    $(this).text(function(i, currentText){
        return currentText === 'Expand All' ? 'Collapse All' : 'Expand All';
    });
    $('body').find("span.destproject").trigger("click");
});
```

How I can make it so my #expandcollapse actually expands all/collapses all?

Comment: As Steve points out on his answer, each call to toggle switches state from "hide" to "show" based upon the item's current state. To achieve your desired effect you need to run .hide() on each applicable visible element when collapsing, and .show() when expanding. - or use toggle(true)/toggle(false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without disecting your code completely, I will just point out that jQuery's `toggle` method simply switches the visibility from `show` to `hide` and vice-versa.  If you just want to toggle in one direction, you can do:

`.toggle(true)` to show and
`.toggle(false)` to hide

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Still can't figure out how to get my arrows to align properly when that button is clicked though...

Answer (score 0):

Using toggle will do that.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully this little example could get you on your way there:

```
$('#expandcollapse').click(function () {
    $('.projectscontainer').each(function () {
        //Code to manipulate the elements here, like .show()/.hide()
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can simply do

```
$("#expandcollapse").on("click",function(e) {
    $(".projectscontainer").find(".srcprojects").toggleSlide();
});
```

This will also give you a nice slideUp/Down animation when the slides are toggled.